# ionic 3 input data binding is updating the different arrays of same type

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a problem in input data-binding for one of our ionic 3 application. Whenever input changes which is changing the array values of different arrays of same type.

Here is my HTML

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of storageItem ; index as i">
        <div class ="itemList">

            <input type="number" [value] ="item.storageOrderQuantity"  (blur)="updateInputItemValue(item)"
                             [(ngModel)]="item.storageOrderQuantity" />

        </div>
    </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

When ever input value changes, it is updating 'storageItem' array along with other arrays which has the same object(there are some other arrays 'item').

Here is my arrays declaration. Item is a model class.

```
item: Item[];
storageItem: Item[] = [];
```

storageItem' is a subset of 'item

Can anybody tell what would be the mistake in data-biding?

Comment: Use different obj in input, with the same obj you doing two-way binding...

Comment: Yeah tried with different object but still the same issue.

Comment: Tried removing the [value] but still the other array objects are changing. I have not assigned these two arrays anywhere(like : this.item = this.storageItem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned that **storageItem is a subset of item**

You probably already know this, Arrays and Object use concept of **assign-by-reference**. If you don't know this then read below article on Medium.

https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600

So if you have the same object in both the arrays then updating one array will update the another,

```
const obj = { name : 'value' };
const arr1 = [1,2,3,obj];
const arr2 = [4,5,6,obj];

obj.name = 'yash'; // both arrays will have updated object
```

Now if you want to avoid this, then you can create a copy of the object before using it in another array.

Take reference from https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-clone-javascript-object/

```
item: Item[] = [
    { id : 'item1', list : [] }, 
    { id : 'item2', list : [] }, 
    { id : 'storageItem', list : [...storageItem] }
];
storageItem: Item[] = [list of storage items];
```

Now `storageItem` and `item > id='storageItem'` point to different arrays.
So your template will only update the `storageItem` now.

Comment: Yes I have used spread operator whenever I am changing the value. Problem is input change is two way data binding it is directly changing the value when ever input changes.

Comment: Which array you want to get updated or which one you don't? I am confused now. Can you explain little more?

Comment: If you don't want two-way binding, just lose the `ngModel`.

Comment: storageItem should get updated but whenever I change object in storageItem, same Item object is automatically changing in Item array.

Comment: How are items and storageItem getting their values? Please share code

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have changed object assignment to spread operator. Its working now.